# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{1+n^2}+\frac{n}{4+n^2}+\cdots+ \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\frac{n}{1+n^2}+\frac{n}{4+n^2}+\cdots+ \frac{n}{n^2+n^2}\right)$$

I will give my solution, which, to my surprise, turned out to be erroneous:

$S_n=\frac{a_1+a_n}{2}n=\frac{\frac{n}{1+n^2}+\frac{n}{n^2+n^2}}{2}n=\frac{1}{4}\frac{3n^2+1}{1+n^2}$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}S_n=\frac{3}{4}$

But the correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$

I do not understand how to get the exact answer.

Comment: This series is not arithmetic.

Comment: Please use the exact question as the title.

Answer (score 4):

Divide  the general term $\dfrac{n}{k^2+n^2}$ by $n^2$ we have : $\dfrac{1}{n}\cdot \dfrac{1}{1+ \frac{k^2}{n^2}} \to \displaystyle \int_{0}^{1} \dfrac{dx}{1+x^2}= \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ .

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

You can rewrite it as a Riemann sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2+k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{n^2\Bigl(1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}\Bigr)}=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k^2}{n^2}}.$$
Can you proceed?